# Is access_token hackable (Laravel Passport)?

Tags: vue.js, jwt, access-token, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I am new to VueJS and Laravel (Passport) API stuff. What I am doing is saving the **access_token** *(returned from `oauth/token`)* into a cookie, then using **`Vuex`** to manage the state of the user so that if he presses logout then he will be redirected to login page, so now my question is if I login and copy cookie from that browser and open a new browser and create same cookie using `document.cookie="key=value"` in console then I go to Dashboard *(which can't be accessed without logging in)* it doesn't say anything and logs me in. This way if anyone somehow get admin's `access_token` then he can change settings till the token is refreshed.

I know my question is stupid type but any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, they can do it. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What's wrong? If anyone access it you know what will happen? If one access the token he can go to dashboard or may be all the protected resources.

Comment: People have to be accessed to the login-ed browser to be able to copy the token. Since they already have access to the login-ed browser, then what's wrong if they copy the token and use it on another session? The user exposes his computer to the public and we have nothing to do about that. I think as long as the credentials are unretrievable from the third party then it's fine, we can't do much about that.